# FactoryGirl pass factory to trait

Tags: factory-bot

Is it possible to pass a factory into a trait?

Given the following trait

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    trait :with_user do

    end
  end
end
```

I would like to do something like (pseudo code)

```
FactoryGirl.create(:foo, :with_user(user))
```

Comment: Do you want to pass a user instance to the trait, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out a while ago so thought I should post the solution in case anyone comes across this issue.

I used transients and an after create hook to get the desired result.

`create :foo, :with_user, user: create(:user)`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    trait :with_user do
      transient do
        user nil
      end
      after :create do |foo, evaluator|
        user = evaluator.user || create :user
      end
    end
  end
end
```